# What is Chronicle-Queue MT visibility guarantee in a single process?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

I mean when I write to `java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue` I have a visibility guarantee happens-before. Single object put to the queue happens-before pull of the same object from the queue. 
So I can assume in the reading thread, that any other state of variable is not older then the time at which the object was put to the `LBQueue`.

Do we have the same visibility guarantee in Chronicle-Queue ?

Do we have the same visibility guarantee in any of the usage style ( `methodReader`/`writer` vs `wire().read().object()` ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you have the same (in fact, slightly stronger) guarantee. Each write to Chronicle Queue (in any style) results in a sequence of volatile write/reads to the memory-mapped file, hence provides memory barriers.

Additionally, each write is guarded by a write lock, which is implemented as a CAS-driven update to a value stored in a memory-mapped file.